# How to create activity against a potential customer in Dynamics CRM 2013?

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge, dynamics-crm-2013

I've created a mail merge for the potential customer of a quote in Dynamics CRM 2013. Its working perfectly to send an email to that potential customer. My next step is to create email activity against that record. Please let me know how can I create the email activity against the quote?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a workflow that automatically creates an email activity based on triggers (or on demand) on the Quote record, which could be run on mass or individually depending on your preference. In the workflow you can set the properties of the Email Activity to dynamically personalise the content so that the email does not seem system generated and non-human.